# Exclude from Compile doesn't work for me

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a test file in my module and I don't need it to be included in compilation process so I added it manually to Preferences -> Compiler -> Excludes. After that I still get the compiler error during compilation, so I choosed a file from Messages and clicked "Exclude from Compile" but this doesn't work for me either. Am I doing something wrong or this is an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio builds whatever is in build.gradle file. For now all GUI made changes are not reflected in the build, they only affect IDE itself e.g. highlighting, dependencies etc.

to exclude some sources from compile use sourceSet closure:

```
android {
    ...

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                exclude 'some/unwanted/package/**'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still use the obsolete project structure like it was with IntelliJ IDEA, so I don't use gradle. I've removed my note about AS to avoid confusion.

Comment: still if you use Android Studio building is done using Gradle. Anyway you can align existing project structure with gradle. Here is how http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Project-Structure